# WaitForSingleObject() for the RegNotifyChangeKeyValue() in a thread C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, listener, waitforsingleobject

I am trying to create a thread that will handle [the below MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I have tested the example, changed in it only the path in *lpSubKey* paramater in the [RegOpenKeyEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx) and it is working fine.

Here is the below thread I am trying to create that gives me a pop-up window of:

> r6010 abort()......

### The code:

```
#include <thread>

void listenerTest();

void main(){
std::thread threadTest(listenerTest);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cout << "\ntest non thread\n";
}
```

Inside the `void listenerTest()` is the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the minor changed I have made.

I also tried other approach, for instance, creating the thread without the `WaitForSingleObject()` (which gives that error) but I can't find a way to return a `HANDLE` for `WaitForSingleObject()` which waits OUTSIDE the thread (in the main).

I don't need synchronization between the *threadTest* thread and the main thread. All I am trying to achieve is that the *threadTest* will run for infinite time while main executes.

Any help would be appropriated.

Thank you.

Comment: If the `main` function returns then the process exits as well, killing all threads. And `main` will return unless you have some kind of blocking code in the code, like e.g. waiting for the thread to exit, so if the thread never exist, the `main` function will never return.

Comment: You are correct. What are you suggesting ?

Comment: To actually *add* synchronization between the threads. When the `main` function wants to return, it should tell the other threads you have created that they should exit, and then in `main` wait for all the threads to exit before you return from `main`.

Comment: threadTest.join(); did the trick. Is that the correct way ?

Comment: Yes it's the way to wait for threads to exit.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are welcome to post your answer.

Comment: Slight nitpick re @JoachimPileborg 's comment: If the destructor is called on a thread which isn't joined or detached, `terminate` is called. This is somewhat different from _"main process exits, killing other threads"_ insofar as the main thread will die a horrible death upon leaving `main` and static destructors will not be called. So it doesn't just affect the extra threads, but also the main thread.